# What kind of chart has a count of objects?

Tags: charts

I was trying to figure out how to make a chart like this but can't seem to find any information. I can't even find a name for this type of chart to Google it.

Does anyone know what these type of charts are called?

This is actually a little different that what I normally see. This is more of a percentage while most represent a certain number of people (one person = 100,000 people)

[image]

Here's a better example. I want to try to make something like this programmatically so it can be populated by data.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a chart and more of an [Infographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infographic). It's used to visual display facts or statistics in a friendly and accessible manner. There are [plenty of tools](http://piktochart.com/) on-line that can help you make one of these, but generally they're made custom by graphic designers using image processing tools such as [Adobe Illustrato](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/illustrator.html)r or [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) (free).

Comment: I added a better example. I'm trying to create something like the new people chart programmatically using data. The **Infographics** in Wikipedia look like they are drawn like you mention but the ones I'm thinking of look more like they can be created dynamically. I think I can create it with a **MATRIX** in **SSRS** but was trying to find out if someone had done this already.